# Need help with calc 2 problem just with setting up the integral

Tags: calculus

The work required to pump all of the water out of the top of a spherical tank with a radius of 27 feet.

I know how to integrate but I do not know what I'm supposed to be integrating.

Comment: If you have no idea how to set up the integral, then it's time to go and check your textbook and notes for similar examples. Have you seen any work problems involving pumping a tank out before?

Comment: You need to find the weight of the water, and how far it needs to be lifted.  You can think of the water as a sequence of parallel cross sections.  The volume of each is $\pi r^2 dh.$  The weight of each will be the volume times the density.  And each needs to be lifted $h$ units.

Comment: so the integral of πr2 dy with r in terms of y

Comment: You still need to multiply that by the distance pumped (also a function of y) and you need the density of water in there somewhere.

Comment: ok, thank you I would also need -32.2 for gravity as well

Comment: In theory... but $62.43 \frac {lbs}{ft^3} $ incorporates the gravitational constant.  If you did this in metric, you would need a $g$ factor (but not a really a density factor since the density of water is 1)